# multi factor anova when only one factor is controllable and the others are not

Tags: anova, experiment-design, engineering-statistics

Using an example of baking a crepe cake, assume that there are 3 layers to the cake, with each layer having 3 flavors. The bakery then assigns three bakers, one to each layer. The goal is to experiment and determine the best combination of 3 layers to achieve the tastiest cake.

Assuming we are the last baker, the cakes are baked in batches of 30 and scored. So we can assign the first 10 cakes in the batch to be flavor 1, the 11-20 cake to be flavor 2, and 21-30 to be flavor 3.

The complication is that we do not know what the first two bakers did and we cannot coordinate with them. The batch of 30 cakes will then be baked and scored.

So after the scores are released, we need to analyze for our particular step (the last layer) which flavor is the best. We can perform a single factor ANOVA for the last layer and treat the first two layer as random noise. However, after the score is released, we will know how the first two bakers "split" the batch of 30 cakes into different flavours. Since we cannot coordinate with the first two bakers, the design of experiment might not be that neat where we have equal amounts of different combinations. There might even be cases where certain combinations are missing.

In such a scenario, can we still use a multi-factor ANOVA or should we perform a single factor ANOVA for each layer and then individually analyze for each layer, what is the best flavour? Also, if the results indicate that flavor1 is the best for the last layer, is there anyway I can check if there are any effects from the first 2 layers?

The reason I came up with this rather convoluted example is because in semiconductor manufacturing, there are 100s of steps in manufacturing a chip. We already have a baseline process but are trying to improve the entire process. However, each engineer can only make changes for their own particular steps. Other engineers are also making changes at the same time. While we try to avoid conflicts by ensuring changes occurs at steps "far away" from each other, I am looking for a method that can check if other engineer's changes might affect my experiment results or not.